# How to click a javascript enabled anchor element using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, linktext

This is the html of the element I am trying to click:

```
<a id="sd3" class="node"
href="/cgi-bin/luci/;stok=753940cb907c7e8524cfaf3c5227614c/expert/configuration/network/wlan" 
target="mainFrame" onclick="javascript: d.s(3);">Wireless LAN 2.4G</a>
```

This is the error raised:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

From the F12 inspection screen, this is the xpath:

```
//*[@id="sd3"]
```

This is the selector:

```
#sd3
```

This is the full xpath:

```
/html/body/div[3]/div/ul/li[2]/div/ul/li/div/ul/li[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a
```

I tried all of these:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text(url).click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//dTreeNode[3]").click()
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('url').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.node').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//dd1[2]").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a#sd3').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".node[id='sd3']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='sd3']").click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Wireless LAN 2.4G').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='dd1']/div[2]/a[1]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='dd1']/div[2]/a[@id='sd3']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='sd3']").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("sd3").click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Wireless LAN 2.4G').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/ul/li[2]/div/ul/li/div/ul/li[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='sd3']").click()
```

Conclusion:
I must admit that I find myself completely clueless to find that despite all my different attempts, it is this very same exception being raised. And yet I'm using the same line of codes earlier in my script and it works like a dime. I even tried to give the content time to generate (3 seconds) cause it's dynamically generated. I'm led to 2 conclusions. I'm either the problem which I couldn't find, or the fact that this is some dynamically generated content is adding a layer of complexity for Selenium that I didn't get.

Comment: is there an `<iframe>` on the webpage?

Comment: always put URL so we could see full HTML and test it in browser.

Comment: did you try to sleep longer time - ie. 10 seconds ?

Comment: @frianH No there is no iframe.

Comment: @furas It is my gateway routeur config webpage so it's local only, sorry. I did try longer and it didn't work also.

Comment: you will have to show more HTML to see problem. If element is inside `<iframe>` then you have to use `driver.switch_to.frame(...)`  because `Selenium treads `iframe` as separated page and it has to get access to its elements. BTW: do you see this element in browser controlled by Selenium ? If it is router config then it may need login before get data.

Answer (score 0):

The `<a>` element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element. So to `click()` on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Wireless LAN 2.4G"))).click()
  ```
- Using `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Wireless LAN 2"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.node[href$='/expert/configuration/network/wlan']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='node' and contains(@href, 'expert/configuration/network/wlan')][contains(., 'LAN 2.4G')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> **Note**: You can find a relevant discussion in [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried all 3 and this is the result : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\EliteBook8460p\Desktop\Selenium\selenium wifi soft.py", line 53, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Wireless LAN 2.4G"))).click()
  File "C:\Users\EliteBook8460p\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: @David Did you check the reference discussion on how to address **NoSuchElementException**?

Comment: I will check into it! Thanks a lot